# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, linux, debian, mariadb

Установил `mariadb-server` и `mariadb-client`. После установил `phpmyadmin`, всё устанавливал через `sudo apt-get install`. Потом поставил пароль для `root`, через `mysql_secure_installation`, так как при установке пароль не запрашивало. Но `phpmyamin` не пускает с ошибкой, которая написана в заголовке. НО в терминале `mysql/mariadb -u root -p` спокойно пускает. Буду рад любой помощи. Debian 9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Столкнулся с подобной проблемой на дебиан. Из симптомов:  от пользователя не пускало даже в консоль mysql, не важно кто значился в -u , а от рута или через sudo пускало всех и без пароля. Правда, пользователь ничего не мог сделать, даже выйти из консоли.

В итоге помогло следующее решение через консоль:

```
use mysql;
update user set plugin='' where User='root';
flush privileges;
```